# Is it possible to save the workspace between different (Plugin) runs?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I want to manually test some features of a plugin I'm developing. To do so, it'd be nice to be able to create some projects in the test Eclipse instance and have them stay throughout all my testing season. At the moment it seems that Eclipse insists on clearing the Eclipse Plugin workspace. Is it possible to invert its default behavior?

Thanks

Comment: Not exactly sure what you are trying to do.  Are you talking about clicking on Debug -> Debug as -> JUnit plugin test? Or are you talking about headless testing? Are you talking about maintaining the same workspace across launches?  Or across test runs in the same launch?

Comment: "clicking on Debug -> Debug as -> JUnit plugin test" & "maintaining the same workspace across launches".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Open up the launch configuration for this launch
2. On the *Main* tab, unclick *Clear* so the workspace remains across launches (alternatively, you can select *Ask for confirmation...* so you can choose each time).

As far as I know, there is no way to mark this as the default.